# C# Casting item from SqlConnection to expose available items

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlconnection

I have a SQL query which I'm calling directly in code using plain ADO.NET (not Entity Framework) due to the stored procedure containing a pivot table which can potentially return a variable number of columns depending on the parameter input.

I've got to the stage where I can get a list of row data from the query and while debugging, if I drill down deep enough on the base properties, I can see that the object contains the 2 properties that I need (`_fieldNameLookup` and `_values`).

I am trying to access these values but I am not sure how I'm meant to be casting the items to expose the properties that I need.

The C# query is as follows:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Services"].ToString()))
{
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "[SPROCQUERY]";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    var queryData = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    var crei = new List<Items>();

    while (queryData.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < queryData.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            var x = queryData[i]; <-- I am trying to expose values in this object
        }
    }

    queryData.Close();

    return null;
}
```

Using intellisense on `var x` shows up with generic properties such as `Equals`, `GetType`, `ToString`.

Thanks

Comment: The indexer for `DbDataReader` returns an object - you don't know at compile time what the type is, so it just shows you the methods on `object`.

Comment: What are you expecting the column types to be?

Comment: These are private fields considering their naming and by looking at the [reference source here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs). The field type FieldNameLookup is also an internal class. These are fields of the SqlDataReader class. The indexer you are calling should already be returning the value of the specific column for the current row so what is wrong?

Comment: Currently, I'm trying to get 1 int column, and a variable number of int? columns (due to the pivot table in the SPROC).

Comment: You can use GetFieldType(i) to get the field type but this is runtime information, not compile time

Comment: Ah right, so there's actually no way to iterate through those 2 lists that I mentioned before then and I have to just use the "Get" methods across the whole dataset then? (and find out when a complete row is finished by checking if the same column name appears again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`queryData` is your DbDataReader.  Referencing an index on the default property simply returns an object of the column number.

To find out the column name, use the `GetName()` method of `queryData`, and to get the type, use `GetFieldType()`:

```
Type t = queryData.GetFieldType(i);
```

To reference properties of your object--you need to cast it to the appropriate type.

Comment: Ah right, I see so you use the GetName() method for column names. Regarding on casting the appropriate type, I'm not sure if I'm understanding how SqlConnection objects work properly, but is there a way to cast the "queryData" to a type so I can access the properties shown while debugging (namely the _fieldNameLookup and _values collection)? Or is the only way to get data out of queryData is to use the "Get" methods? Thanks

Comment: You have to know what type the object is in order to be able to cast it into a type you can get to the properties on.  In your code above, "x" will be a type object, and intellisense has no way of determining the actual underlying type, since it won't be known until runtime.  However, if you put a breakpoint there, the debugger will allow you to fully query x, since its type will now be know.  To get intellisense to work, you need to cast x into an object of the correct type, and then intellisense will work on that new object.

Comment: Alright, I see. I initially thought there was some casting I could do on the queryData object itself (the raw object you get from ExecuteReader in order to access the list properties I needed), but it seems you have to iterate through the queryData and read the information using the "Get" methods. Thanks for your help.